# Set default for transparency savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib, save

I want to save all my images with transparent=True by default,
so I can type:

```
savefig(fname.png)
```

instead of

```
savefig(fname.png, transparent=True).
```

Can this be done by setting a rcParams entry? Or do I have to create a new function?

Comment: Please create an issue on github to add this feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the newly added (
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2388)

```
rcParams['savefig.transparent']
```